# Sarima show only plots

Tags: r

I have the following code that I am running in R:

````
```{r}
library(astsa)
data = c(1:500)
mo1 = sarima(data,0,0,2)
```
````

It produces both the five plots I am interested in and output from the nonlinear optimization routine. I don't want the output from the nonlinear optimization however to turn it off using `details=FALSE` I will also turn off the plots which I need.

When I run this code in the console, the plots are put into a pdf and the optimization output is printed to STDOUT. This is good because I can have the plots and optimization separately which is what I need, however I want to do this in RStudios. How can this be done?

Comment: does `mo1 = capture.output(sarima(data,0,0,2))` work?

Comment: ... in fact a dirty move to recode `details`:  `body(sarima)[[18]] = quote(trc <- abs(details-1))` then `mo1 = sarima(data,0,0,2, details = TRUE)` , although a better move would be to ask the author if they would separate the arguments for the optimisation trace and producing the plots.

Comment: yes @user20650, this worked, thanks, if you want the bounty go ahead and post this as an answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `details` argument is used to both return the `trace` output from the optimisers -- see the lines in `sarima`:

```
trc = ifelse(details, 1, 0)
```

and various

```
optim.control = list(trace = trc, REPORT = 1, reltol = tol)
```

and to produce the plots

```
if (details) {
  < code for plots>
}
```

A couple of options to produce the plots but no optimiser output would be to:

1. capture the output from the optimiser:

   ```
   mo1 = capture.output(sarima(data,0,0,2))
   ```

   but then you either have to parse the captured output to get the fit statistics or need to run `sarima` a second time (`mo1 = sarima(data,0,0,2, details=FALSE)`) to get the statistics.
2. change the body of the function to change what the argument `details` does:

   ```
   body(sarima)[[18]] = quote(trc <- abs(details-1)) 
   mo1 = sarima(data,0,0,2, details = TRUE)
   ```
3. Another option  would be to [request that the authors](https://github.com/nickpoison/astsa) change the function to separate the optimiser trace and plot commands (i.e. add a `plot=TRUE` type argument to the function signature and change `if(details)` to `if(plot)`).

Answer (score 1):

It's been a couple of years but this will produce only the plots when knitted:

````
```{r results='hide',fig.keep='all'}
sarima(data,0,0,2)
```
````